# Android WebView: Setting iframe src redirects the page

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iframe, android-webview

I am playing a youtube embeded video in my jquery ui dialog which has iframe in it. On dialogClose event i clear the iframe src but it redirects/postback the page to that url. here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="videoDialog" title="Video Player">
    <iframe id="videoPlayer" src="" width="100%" height="500" style="border: 0px;" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"></iframe>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $videoDialog = $("#videoDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,                    
        width: 900,
        height: "auto", 
        modal: true
    }),
    $iframeVideoPlayer = $("#videoPlayer");        


$(".video").on("click", function(){   
    $iframeVideoPlayer.prop("src", $(this).data("src"));
    $videoDialog.dialog("open");
  });

  $videoDialog.on("dialogclose", function(event) {           
     $iframeVideoPlayer.prop("src", "");//i set empty src here to iframe and it redirects the page     
  });
```

Please help.

Its only happening inside android webview. In desktop browsers it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the dialog from DOM on dialog close event and inserted the dialog in DOM on the fly to stop redirecting page on setting iframe src:

here is my code:

```
var $videoDialog = $("#videoDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,                    
        width: 900,
        height: "auto", 
        modal: true,
        close: function() {
            $videoDialog.remove();
        }
    }),
    $iframeVideoPlayer = $("#videoPlayer");     

    $(".video").on("click", function(){

       var videoSrc = $(this).data("src"); 

       $videoDialog = $("#videoDialog");  

       if($videoDialog.length == 0){

          //here appending dialog in body and .dialog it   
          $("body").append("<div id='videoDialog' title='Video Player'><iframe id='videoPlayer' src='"+videoSrc+"' width='100%' height='500' style='border: 0px;'></iframe></div>");

          $videoDialog = $("#videoDialog").dialog({
              autoOpen: false,                    
              width: 900,
              height: "auto", 
              modal: true,
              close: function() {               
                $videoDialog.remove();
              }
         });

        $iframeVideoPlayer = $("#videoPlayer");
     }

     $iframeVideoPlayer.prop("src", videoSrc);      
     $videoDialog.dialog("open");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `beforeClose` event?